# how to deploy GWT app to tomcat

Tags: gwt, tomcat7

I searched this site for answer to this question and couldn't find a solution.
what i did is that i simply compress the war directory in my eclipse GWT app project then rename it to .war then drop it to tomcat webapps folder.
when i run the web app, the first screen is successfully shown but when i call a servlet within my  src code it gives me resource not found by tomcat server. 
i'm sure i have added entry for servlet in web.xml file and the app worked well when i run it in eclipse gwt dev mode. something prevent my servlets (standard servlets not GWT RPC servlets) to be found and executed by tomcat. what could be the reason?

---

### UPDATE

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Servlets -->

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OAuth</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.goauth.server.OAuthServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OAuth</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/goauth/oauth</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OAuthCallback</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.goauth.server.OAuthCallbackServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OAuthCallback</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/goauth/callback</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.goauth.server.OAuthServiceImpl</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/goauth/service</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>OAuthConfirm</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.goauth.server.OAuthConfirmServlet</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>OAuthConfirm</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/goauth/confirm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>GOAuth.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>    
</web-app>
```

---

### Error

nothing in tomcate logs files
the only error in browser is :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /goauth/oauth

type Status report

message /goauth/oauth

description The requested resource (/goauth/oauth) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
```

Comment: Can you show us your web.xml and the stack trace you get?

Comment: ok give some time to get back to my code in my other Mac book machine. i'll post the info soon.thnx

Comment: i have added web.xml file and the error i get when i press a button that calls servlet /goauth/oauth. this servlet could not be found by tomcat even though all exists in war file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem :
for invoking my servlet i was calling a url of the format : `"/goauth/OAuth"` 
this worked with eclipse gwt plugin in dev mode but not when i deploy war to tomcat server.
the solution is that my url pointing to my servlet should be of the form :

```
String href = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"goauth/OAuth";
```

so we need to tell tomcat the full url by prefixing servlet url with GWT.getHostPageBaseURL().

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, 
I get tomcat UnsatisfiedLinkError on either GWT.getModuleBaseUrl() or GWT.getHostPageBaseUrl().
What am I doing wrong?

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.getModuleBaseURL()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: maybe you are using the GWT.getHostPageBaseUrl() on server side. you can't do that as this is only client side code and can't be used in server side

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response othman.
I am actually calling it on the server. So is there any way to find the path on server side?

Comment: in your server code you will have a `request` object and the path is `request.getContextPath()`  .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how to create a GWT .war in eclipse: http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/

Comment: i did same thing in this link tutorial but i have same error. i've updated my question with web.xml file . when i call servlet /goauth/oauth the server returns 404.

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping, try changing
/goauth/oauth
to /OAuth

Comment: no Mr maneesh your solution doesn't work! -anybody else have a solution?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /OAuth

type Status report

message /OAuth

description The requested resource (/OAuth) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.20