# WARNING: /%3C%=request.getContextPath()%%3E/trailpath/trailpath.nocache.js: java.lang.NumberFormatException: =r

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets, jetty

i am giving code.
**Client**

```
 package a.b.client;
 public class Trail implements EntryPoint{

Button b=new Button("Click");
FlowPanel fs=new FlowPanel();

int i=0;
private final TrailInterfaceAsync obj = GWT
        .create(TrailInterface.class);
@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
    RootPanel.get().add(b);
    RootPanel.get().add(fs);
    b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            obj.getDetails(new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String>>(){

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> result) {

                    try{
                    System.out.println("size:"+result.size());
                    for(i=1;i<=result.size()-1;i++)
                    {
                        HTML l=new HTML(result.get(i).toString());

                        fs.add(l);
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }});

        }});

}

}
```

**Server**

```
package a.b.server;
import a.b.client.TrailInterface;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;


public class TrailImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements TrailInterface {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public ArrayList<String> getDetails() {
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    ArrayList<String> details=new ArrayList<String>();

try
{
    System.setSecurityManager(null);
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    con = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://69.162.121.114:3306/AyushCareDB?"
                  + "user=xxxxx&password=yyyyyy");
    if(con!=null)
        System.out.println("success!");
        else
            System.out.println("fail!");


    stmt = con.createStatement();
          // Result set get the result of the SQL query
          resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from LocationTable");
          while(resultSet.next())
          {
             details.add(resultSet.getString(1));
          }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return details;

}

}
```

**web.xml**

```
  <!-- Servlets -->
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>TrailImpl</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>a.b.server.TrailImpl</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>TrailImpl</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/trailpath/trail</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Trail.html</welcome-file>
```

when i did Run As-Web Application
it showing error like this:

```
Jul 18, 2013 5:02:09 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /%3C%=request.getContextPath()%%3E/trailpath/trailpath.nocache.js:     java.lang.NumberFormatException: =r
```

i couldn't understand this where it come from? please help me.

as well as i tried to deploy this simple GWT project in Tomcat while it is working before(suddenly it showing above error).i didn't change any thing now. but getting above error. while it is working, i got fallowing error which is in post. but where i have to use GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() or GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() method in my code. i dont have any redirection to other pages hear. i couldn't found any solution for this.

POST:[how to deploy GWT app to tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209868/how-to-deploy-app-to-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I'd say that you're referencing the trailing.nocache.js files from your Trail.html page using JSP syntax, but Trail.html is not evaluated as a JSP by the server (by default, only *.jsp files are treated as JSP).

The `NumberFormatException: =r` comes from the server when evaluating the URL (`%3C%=request`) where it expects `%=r` (from `%=request`) to evaluate as a URL escape. The `NumberFormatException` thus comes from trying to parse `=r` as an hexadecimal number.

**Solution:** remove the JSP syntax from your Trail.html page, or change that page to be evaluated as JSP (e.g. rename it to `Trail.jsp`)